# ¿Cómo hacer una sopa de letras en python?

Tags: python

Debo crear una una sopa una sopa de letras de tamaño NxN donde N y el listado de palabras son datos ingesados por el usuario.
Primero debe revisar si el tamaño N de la sopa de letras es suficiente para albergar la longitud de las palabras, de lo contrario deberá emitir un error.
La construcción debe incluir palabras horizontales y verticales en ambos sentidos, palabras diagonales con pendiente positiva y negativa y palabras superpuestas, es decir, que una palabra vertical puede usarse para una palabra horizontal.

He estado intentando hacerlo con funciones, pero no se como implementarlas todas en la sopa con las palabras ingresadas, además no sé con hacer las palabras superpuestas.

```
import random 


alfabeto=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

def crear_matrix(N):
    matrix =[]
    for i in range(N):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(N):
            matrix[i].append(" ")
            matrix[i][j]=alfabeto[random.randint(0, 25)]
    return matrix

def de_izquierda_a_derecha(matrix,palabra):
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        matrix[N-1][i]= palabra[ i ]
    return matrix

def de_derecha_a_izquierda(matrix, palabra):
    palabra=palabra[::-1]
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        matrix[N-3][i-len(palabra)]=palabra[i]
    return matrix

def de_arriba_abajo(matrix,palabra):
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        matrix[i][N-1]= palabra[ i ]
    return matrix

def de_abajo_arriba(matrix, palabra):
    palabra=palabra[::-1]
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        matrix[i-len(palabra)][N-3]=palabra[i]
    return matrix

def diagonal_de_arriba_abajo(matrix, palabra):
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        matrix[i][i]= palabra[ i ]
    return matrix

def diagonal_de_abajo_arriba(matrix, palabra):
    palabra=palabra[::-1]
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        matrix[i-len(palabra)][i]= palabra[ i ]
    return matrix   

N=int(input())
numero_de_palabras=int(input())
for i in range(numero_de_palabras):
    lista_palabras=[]
    palabras=input()
    lista_palabras.append(palabras)
    if len(palabras)>N:
        print("la palabra no se puede incluir en la sopa de letras")
    print(lista_palabras)`
```

Esto es lo que he hecho hasta el momento pero no se si sea correcto, agradecería mucho su ayuda. :)

Answer (score 2):

Tengo una solución que no es óptima, pero que produce resultados aceptables.

El método consiste en partir con una matriz vacía y luego ir seleccionando palabras al azar. Por cada palabra se selecciona una posición al azar dentro de la matriz. Al azar también se termina en que dirección se llenaran las celdas.

Las reglas a respetar son:

1. Nunca sobrescribir una celda ocupada.
2. Toda palabra cabe completa en la matriz.

La solución usa dos clases: `Cursor` y `Matrix`.

**Clase Cursor**

La clase `Cursor` almacena las coordenadas de una celda y la dirección de avance. Con `Cursor.next()` podemos ir recorriendo las celdas en la dirección indicada.

El método `__init__` se encarga de calcular al azar la dirección de avance que se usara por el resto de la existencia.

El método `next` avanza una cantidad de pasos en la dirección precalculada.

EL método `es_valido` retorna True si las actuales coordenadas del cursor caen dentro de la matriz.

```
class Cursor:
    def __init__(self, fila, columna):
        self.fila = fila
        self.columna = columna
        self.avanX = [-1, 0, 1][random.randint(0,2)]
        self.avanY = [-1, 0, 1][random.randint(0,2)]
        if self.avanX == 0 and self.avanY == 0:
            self.avanX = 1

    def next(self, pasos=1):
        self.fila += pasos * self.avanX
        self.columna += pasos * self.avanY

    def es_valido(self, dimension):
        return 0 <= self.fila < dimension and 0 <= self.columna < dimension

    def __str__(self):
        return f"[{self.fila} {self.avanX}, {self.columna} {self.avanY}]"
```

**Clase Matrix**

La clase `Matrix` define una matriz de NxN.

Se usa un objeto `Cursor` como indice dentro de la matriz. En este ejemplo, se declara una matriz de 10x10 y se almacena una 'a' en la segunda fila, tercera columna:

```
matriz = Matrix(10)
cursor = Cursor(1,2)
matriz[cursor] = 'a'
```

Los métodos `__setitem__` y `__getitem__` no se llaman directamente. Ambas son el respaldo que permite acceder a las celdas usando `[]`.

El método `put` intenta colocar una palabra en la matriz. Para ello se crea un cursor a partir de una fila, columna aleatoria y se comprueba si a partir de ese cursor se puede colocar la palabra completa sin salirse de los bordes de la matriz.

Si la palabra es aceptable, se avanza por la matriz y en cada celda se reemplaza el blanco previo con la letra correspondiente de la palabra. Si la celda ya está ocupada, no se reemplaza.

La clase también guarda la lista de palabras que fueron aceptadas completas en la matriz, junto con sus coordenadas. Una palabra puede aceptar en forma incompleta, si alguna de las celdas que debía ocupar ya estaban ocupadas de antes con un valor distinto.

Código

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        valores = [' '] * dimension * dimension
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.matriz = np.array(valores).reshape((dimension, dimension))
        self.libres = dimension * dimension
        self.palabras = []

    def __getitem__(self, cursor):
        if cursor.es_valido(self.dimension):
            return self.matriz[cursor.fila][cursor.columna]
        else:
            return ' '

    def __setitem__(self, cursor, value):
        if cursor.es_valido(self.dimension):
            if self.matriz[cursor.fila][cursor.columna] == ' ':
                self.libres -= 1
            self.matriz[cursor.fila][cursor.columna] = value

    def put(self, palabra):
        x, y = random.randint(0, self.dimension - 1), random.randint(0, self.dimension - 1)
        cursor = Cursor(x,y)

        largo = len(palabra)
        cursor.next(largo)
        if not cursor.es_valido(self.dimension):
            return False
        cursor.next(-largo)

        restantes = largo 
        for indice in range(largo):
            if self[cursor] == ' ' or self[cursor] == palabra[indice]:
                self[cursor] = palabra[indice]
                restantes -= 1
            cursor.next()

        if restantes == 0:
            # Esta palabra aparece completa en la matriz
            self.palabras.append((x, y, cursor.avanX, cursor.avanY, palabra))

        return True

    def __str__(self):
        regla = f"   {('0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ' * int (self.dimension / 10 + 1))[:self.dimension * 2]}\n"
        linea = regla
        for i in range(self.dimension):
            linea += f"{i:2d} {' '.join(self.matriz[i].tolist())}\n"
        return linea + regla
```

**Comprobación**

```
import numpy as np
import random

palabras = ["campo", "arado", "caballo", "vaca", "oveja", "tractor", "semilla"]
DIM = 10
matriz = Matrix(DIM)
while matriz.libres:
    palabra = palabras[random.randint(0, len(palabras) - 1)]
    largo = len(palabra)
    matriz.put(palabra)

print(matriz)
print(matriz.palabras)
```

produce

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0 c a o p a r a d o c
 1 a r c v a a a v r r
 2 b v o o v a c a a o
 3 a a p t v p e a v v
 4 l r m a c e b a v e
 5 l a o r o a j j o j
 6 o o d j d c r a a a
 7 a o p m a c l t c c
 8 c a r a o l o r r c
 9 t r a c a j e v o a
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

[(2, 4, 0, 1, 'vaca'), (0, 0, 1, 0, 'caballo'), (4, 8, -1, -1, 'vaca'), (0, 4, 0, 1, 'arado'), (2, 3, 1, 1, 'oveja'), (2, 9, 1, 0, 'oveja'), (7, 7, -1, -1, 'tractor'), (9, 8, 0, -1, 'oveja'), (7, 5, 0, -1, 'campo')]
```

Interpretación: `(2, 4, 0, 1, 'vaca')` dice que en fila 2, columna 4, avanzando de a una columna, está la palabra 'vaca'

Nota: dada la naturaleza aleatoria del proceso, cada ejecución obtendrá resultados distinto